# jquery got error event change on select element

Tags: jquery

I got error

> "Use of attributes' specified attribute is deprecated. It always returns true.
>   return !val || val.specified ? elem.value : elem.text;"

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#o_productCategory").change(function(e){
        $.getJSON("URI", ({"parent" : $("#o_productCategory").val()}),function(result) {
            //code here
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error looks related to `$("#o_productCategory").val()`. Possibly [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12072) or [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11397).

Because you're inside `$("#o_productCategory")`'s `change` callback, you could use `this.value` instead.

```
$.getJSON("URI", { "parent" : this.value }, function (result) {
    //code here
});
```